# GCC format of error messages

Tags: java, gcc

I need to implement simple data mining from error messages I get from gcc ( Java app is some JavaIDE for microprocessors which calls GCC in back and I need to tell user error in usable way). Is there any standard format for error messages in GCC ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the format is  `filename:line: message`. Vim also parses gcc output so you can check `:help efm-entries` to see the patterns used.